# Deleting record from a table using eloquont

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to delete a record from a table using eloquent 
So when i do

```
$this->model->find($product_attribute_value_id)->delete();
```

I get this Exception

```
Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
```

I also tried the

```
$this->model->where('product_attribute_value_id',$product_attribute_value_id)->delete();
```

and

```
$this->model->where('product_attribute_value_id',$product_attribute_value_id)->first()->delete();
```

and still give me the same exception

Comment: Where are you using it, and what is `$this->model`?

Comment: Because i use it in a service and i get the same issue  when I use  ProductAttributeValue::

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code? Specifically the service and the full model you're trying to use. It's trying to use `serialize` somewhere, but I don't recall that being in the source files.

Comment: Thank you, problem solved and it's because it has a relation with another table